# Add nullable datetime column to Primary Key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with following columns:

```
[ClauseID] [int] NOT NULL,
[PolicyCategoryID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ExpiryDate] [smalldatetime] NULL,
```

By now `ClauseID` and `PolicyCategoryID` together creates the primary key. But I want `ExpiryDate` also be a part of primary key. To make the column not null I tried the following but it gives an error:

```
ALTER TABLE tblClauses_PolicyCategory
ALTER COLUMN [ExpiryDate] SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '2079-06-06'

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DEFAULT'.
```

Any idea why? Is it not possible to set a default date like this?

EDIT: By bad! Default key was already set. That must be the reason it gave an error.

Comment: Use `alter column` to modify the data type, and `add constraint` to add a default constraint

Comment: Why do you want to make the `ExpiryDate` part of the primary key? Replacing a NULLable column with an arbitrary default of `2079-06-06` (is that YMD or YDM btw?) is very questionable decision.

Comment: 2079-06-06 is the max date you can enter in MS SQL Server. It's not an arbitrary value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
ALTER TABLE tblClauses_PolicyCategory
ALTER COLUMN [ExpiryDate] SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL

ALTER TABLE tblClauses_PolicyCategory ADD CONSTRAINT
cons_expiryDate DEFAULT '2079-06-06' FOR ExpiryDate
```

Before execute these lines, please check if exists some rows with ExpiryDate null, if yes, please, update all nullable rows to default value

Comment: And if you haven't done this already UPDATE all NULL values to the default before setting it to NOT NULL

Comment: What Joe is saying is that you can't add constraints using an ALTER COLUMN, only during add. To do so on a created column you most explicitly add the constraint instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

```
CREATE TABLE tblClauses_PolicyCategory(
[ClauseID] [int] NOT NULL,
[PolicyCategoryID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ExpiryDate] [smalldatetime] NULL)


ALTER TABLE tblClauses_PolicyCategory
ALTER COLUMN [ExpiryDate] SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL 

ALTER TABLE tblClauses_PolicyCategory
ADD CONSTRAINT cons_default DEFAULT '2079-06-06' FOR ExpiryDate
```

But, before changing `ExpireDate` to NOT NULL, you must populate values for existing rows in this column, and then change column to NOT NULL.